# Como evitar que NavigationPage bloquee CarouselPage? [Leer descripción porfavor]

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

Puede ser una pregunta algo tonta, pero me gustaría preguntarlo, les explico, primero puse el CarouselPage para cuando llegara a una ventana, tenga que presionar un botón y avanzar a la siguiente, esto por medio de NavigationPage, pero al hacer esto NavigationPage me sale primero (me bloquea CarouselPage ya que es la página que no tiene el botón) les adjunto la imagen del código donde tengo estos dos pages, no se como acomodarlo para ser honesto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Edicion -> agregado por el comentario

```
InitializeComponent(); 
CarouselPage carouselPage = new CarouselPage(); 
carouselPage.Children. Add(new MainPage()); 
carouselPage.Children. Add(new Config1()); 
MainPage =carousel Page; 
MainPage=new Navigation Page(new MainPage())
```

Comment: Estas sobre escribiendo tu pagina principal por donde entra la aplicacion. El Carrousel deberia ser un componente que vos tenes dentro de tu page o deberias ser una pagina que llamas mediante un boton pero no de esa forma y el navigationPage te sirve para crear la barrar de arriba con el boton de atras y titulo y podes navegar en forma de Pila (Stack) en tus pantallas con push y pop.

Comment: Hola, agrega el código como texto no como imagen ya que no se visualiza correctamente, considera revisar [ask]. saludos

Comment: InitializeComponent(); 
CarouselPage carouselPage = new CarouselPage();
carouselPage.Children. Add(new MainPage());
carouselPage.Children. Add(new Config1()); 
MainPage =carousel Page;

MainPage=new Navigation Page(new MainPage());                            
                                                                 **sorry es que estoy en el celular y se me hace mas rápido ponerlo como comentario

Comment: Ramiro Barone, no comprendo muy bien, a que te refieres con tener el Carousel dentro de un page?

Comment: puedes tener un carousel como si fuera un Entry o picker dentro de la pagina que quieras mostrar la lista de items con ese componente (carousel).